# Bar graph in pgf plots — missing data and get rid of ticks?

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xtick = data,
    ylabel=Size of Slick,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.13)},
    anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ybar interval=1,]
\addplot 
    coordinates {(1, 1.047) (2, 2.005) (3, 3.348) (4, 5.719) (5, 7.273) (6, 8.41) (7, 9.117)};
\addplot 
    coordinates {(1, 1.139) (2, 2.087) (3, 3.413) (4, 5.765) (5, 7.304) (6, 8.426) (7, 9.127)};
\legend{Initial Observation, 10 min. later}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

So this is giving me the plot without the data points for `x=7`. I also want to know how I can get rid of those ugly ticks at the top and righthand side. Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome! You are using `ybar interval` but probably only want `ybar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably only want `ybar` (instead of `ybar interval`) and `xtick pos=lower,ytick pos=left` to remove the ticks on the top and right.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xtick = data,
    ylabel=Size of Slick,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.13)},
    anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ybar,bar width=1em,xtick pos=lower,ytick pos=left]
\addplot 
    coordinates {(1, 1.047) (2, 2.005) (3, 3.348) (4, 5.719) (5, 7.273) (6, 8.41) (7, 9.117)};
\addplot 
    coordinates {(1, 1.139) (2, 2.087) (3, 3.413) (4, 5.765) (5, 7.304) (6, 8.426) (7, 9.127)};
\legend{Initial Observation, 10 min.\ later}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]